# How can Religion take control of a technological society

Tags: technology, planets, space, religion

Rox Dwight is a very well known scientist in the space-faring society of Startopia. He owns the Rox Corporation and the general populace enjoys the wide variety of products that he invents and researchs. Moreover, Rox Dwight has access to a wide-variety of futuristic inventions.

But Rox Dwight wants more...He wishes to take complete control of Startopia through his Religion.

### His Religion

Rox Dwight's vision is to implement the belief that there should be a singular God who can 'gift' certain people with inventions and breakthroughs. Believers of his religion require that they pray to this God and offer some sort of invention or money to this God.

Moreover, Rox plans to implement a meritocratic caste system where those who 'invent' more or discover 'breakthroughs' are ranked up into the caste system. The higher you are in caste, the more your are rewarded, whether it be life longevity, luxurity items etc...  Moreover, Rox wishes to place himself in an 'unreachable' caste and he would eliminate anyone that he deems to threat his own position as Great Leader.

Rox doesn't really believe in this Religion, he only believes that religion is the only way to truly control the massive populace of Startopia and as a result religion must be used.

Also, Rox has successfully 'converted' his entire company into the belief of this Religion.

### His enemies and possible roadblocks.

Even though Rox Corporation is the biggest conglomerate, Rox isnt the only one. In fact, he has a few rivals who currently contest his position.

Startopia is both culturally and ethnically diverse and is spread across different planets in the same solar system but it only exists within that solar system. As a result, Rox's religion must somehow appeal to different cultures and ethnicities.

Due to Startopia's ancient and violent past, the hatred of biological horrors and super weapons is so well embedded that even the insidious Rox Dwight abhors the idea of utilizing them.

It's well known that the current goverment is mixed with honest politicians and corrupt politicians.

**How would Rox Dwight successfully convince and influence the general majority of Startopia to believe and practice his religion?**

Also, sorry if my question is bad in any way. I'm a bit new here so criticism is welcome.

Comment: The easiest way would be through force or piggybacking on another popular religion and state that his is a continuation of the other one.

Comment: Isn't that what's happening right now, only Rox is the Church?

Answer (score 1):

What came to my mind is Scientology when reading your question.  If Rox Dwight is to be placed in an unreachable caste, it's very similar to the stages in Scientology.  Honestly, I don't know much about it, but it seems like this religion would require their followers to have faith in the ones in higher caste systems as they are more in touch with the "divine" or "God" and therefore have more knowledge then they do.

So there must be a very good and plausible reason for why people should follow this religion and listen to higher ups, like Rox Dwight.  He seems to be justifying a position of Papal-like status circa 5<sup>th</sup> century AD - like a Papal supremacy.

Speaking of Papal-like status, another possible reason to follow this religion would be that of **fear**.  Rox Dwight needs to be a master of propaganda, judging by looking at the etymology of the word:

> Originally this word derived from a new administrative body of the Catholic church (congregation) created in 1622, called the Congregatio de Propaganda Fide (Congregation for Propagating the Faith), or informally simply Propaganda.[2][6] Its activity was aimed at "propagating" the Catholic faith in non-Catholic countries.

- Wikipedia - Propaganda:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda

I'm not implying that you have to be fearful to be Catholic, I'm just using this as an example for the sake of answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Politics.**

If we assume that Startopia is a republic, all you need to do is to give candidates friendly to your religion an edge compared to other politicians. In the competitive world of politics this means politicians will rush to respect your beliefs and support your beneficial projects.

You then leverage this to gradually increase your political influence. Which in turn boost your ability to help politicians get elected. This should become a self-sustaining loop.

At some point you then manufacture a crisis or just wait for a real crisis to occur and, with overwhelming popular support, your religion takes over safeguarding the state away from the corrupt and ineffective politicians.

*Deleted a long text getting into the details, manipulating politics is easy but the devil is in details.*